# Stroke(RoundRectBorder) for codenameone

Tags: codenameone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q95VV.jpg)I have a problem with the code below :

```
headerContainer.setUIID("UIID");
 Stroke borderStroke = new Stroke(1, Stroke.CAP_SQUARE, Stroke.JOIN_MITER, 1);
        headerContainer.getAllStyles().setBorder(RoundRectBorder.create().bottomOnlyMode(true).stroke(borderStroke));
```

the transparency applied to the `headerContainer` does not work. knowing that it worked before the last update, but after last update the background of `headerContainer` became white.

[Screenshot Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhHX.jpg)
[Screenshot After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q95VV.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ideally before/after? It's probably a regression due to a fix made to this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2291 but it's unclear to me from the description which transparency isn't working?

Comment: transparency applied to the HeaderContainer in UIID

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem and made a fix for it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/6b5ddb2598bfe7ddeb6255a026d7182dc40eca46

This should be in the build servers on Friday February 9th 2018 (this Friday).